# Terraform - ADF to DB connectivity issue when tenant_id is provided in LS configuration - azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_sql_database

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure

#### Terraform Version

1.2.3

#### AzureRM Provider Version

v3.13.0

#### Affected Resource(s)/Data Source(s)

Azure data factory, SQL Database

#### Terraform Configuration Files

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_sql_database" "sqldatabase_linked_service_10102022" {
  count = (var.subResourcesInfo.sqlDatabaseName != "") ? 1 : 0
  depends_on = [azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_azure.autoresolve_integration_runtime,
  azurerm_data_factory_managed_private_endpoint.sqlserver_managed_endpoint]

  name            = "AzureSqlDatabase10102022"
  data_factory_id = azurerm_data_factory.datafactory.id

  integration_runtime_name = "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime"
  use_managed_identity     = true
  connection_string = format("Integrated Security=False;Data Source=%s.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=%s;",
    var.subResourcesInfo.sqlServerName,
  var.subResourcesInfo.sqlDatabaseName)
}
```

#### Expected Behaviour

Issue is ADF to DB connectivity, error:

Operation on target DWH_DF_aaa failed: {'StatusCode':'DFExecutorUserError','Message':'Job failed due to reason: com.microsoft.dataflow.broker.InvalidOperationException: Only one valid authentication should be used for AzureSqlDatabase. ServicePrincipalAuthentication is invalid. One or two of servicePrincipalId/key/tenant is missing.','Details':''}

When we created this LS using TF, we get tenant="" in ADF LS Json file which we suspect that causing issue of above error.

When we created the same LS directly on ADF UI, then there is no field of tenant="" in its json file, and if we use this LS in dataflow/pipeline then communication works from ADF to DB.

Expected behavior should be, if we don't provide tenant_id parameter in TF code then in json also should not show tenant="" which then works for connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the scenario in my environment:***

With below code , I could create a Linked Service (connection) between Azure SQL Database and Azure Data Factory.

***Code:***

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {
  name                            = "kaADFexample"
  location                        = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name             = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  managed_virtual_network_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "kaaaexample"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_kind             = "BlobStorage"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory_managed_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name               = "example"
  data_factory_id    = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
  target_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
  subresource_name   = "blob"
}


resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "main" {
    depends_on = [data.azurerm_resource_group.example]
    name = "kasupports01-mid"
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    location = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
}


resource "azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_azure" "test" {
  name                    = "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime"
  data_factory_id      = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
  location                = "AutoResolve"
  virtual_network_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_sql_database" "linked_service_azure_sql_database" {
  name                     = "kaexampleLS"
  data_factory_id          = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
  connection_string        = "data source=serverhostname;initial catalog=master;user id=testUser;Password=test;integrated security=False;encrypt=True;connection timeout=30"
  use_managed_identity     = true
  integration_runtime_name = azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_azure.test.name
  
  

depends_on = [azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_azure.test,
azurerm_data_factory_managed_private_endpoint.example]

}



output "id" {
  value = azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_sql_database.linked_service_azure_sql_database.id
}
```

Executed:  terraform plan

[image]

***Output:***

```
id = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/kaADFexample/linkedservices/kaexampleLS"
```

If the error persists in your case ,try  removing the  ***`tenant`*** attribute in the data_factory just after deployment is done in terraform.

[image]

Please check this known issue and mentioned by  @chgenzel in [terraform-provider-azurerm issues | Github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/14577)

**ADF**:

[image]

**Managed Identity**

[image]

**Linked service** : azure sql

[image]

**Reference:** [data_factory_linked_service_azure_sql_database | terraformregistry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_linked_service_azure_sql_database#integration_runtime_name)

Comment: > question is not about if the LS and other resources are being created or not, which is creating ofcourse. But for LS in question is not working as expected due to the fact that, terraform is adding tenant="",  yes I know after removing manually its working fine. but I don't expect to remove manually. And that's the same question in github but no answer on it as well.